# SQL: How to filter product with all listed attribute_value IDS PostgreSQL?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM query builder to filter my products. Here is my Product entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Product extends MedusaProduct {
  @ManyToMany(() => AttributeValue)
  @JoinTable()
  attribute_values: AttributeValue[];
}
```

And here is Attribute value table:

```
@Entity()
export class AttributeValue extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  value: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Attribute, (a) => a.values)
  attribute: Attribute;

  @Column({ type: "jsonb", nullable: true })
  metadata: Record<string, unknown>;

  @Column({ type: "boolean", default: false })
  is_bool: boolean;

  @Column({ type: "int" })
  rank: number;

  @BeforeInsert()
  private beforeInsert(): void {
    this.id = generateEntityId(this.id, "attr_val");
  }
}
```

My goal is to filter products based on attribute value ids list:

Example:

I have product list:

```
product-1 attributes: [1,2,3,4] 
product-2 attributes: [3,4] 
product-3 attributes: [1,2]
```

Expected behavior:

```
List of attributes: [1,2]; Result: [product-1, product-3]
List of attributes: [1,2,3,4]; Result: product-1
List of attributes: [3,4]; Result: product-1,product,2
```

I tried to use IN operator but it works more like and OR operator.

Comment: Do you want a SQL answer or a typeorm answer?

Comment: All answers will apreciated